# When running make check on Mesos one of the tests fails, what now?

Tags: unit-testing, build, mesos

After running a `make check` when building Mesos, I found that one of those tests is failing. How can I find out more about the reasoning behind that failure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note** `make check` needs to be run before the following can be used as `make check` renders the needed binaries.

The following assumes that your current directory (`pwd`) is the `build` folder within the extracted / cloned Mesos project directory structure.

Let's assume that a test named `Foo.Bar` had failed for you. Now go ahead and run that test individually, with enhanced output:

`./bin/mesos-tests.sh --gtest_filter="Foo.Bar" --verbose`

That should reveal some more insights of the failure reasoning.

In cases where the above still has too little output to understand the problem, for some rare cases, it could be beneficial to increase the verbosity even further.

`GLOG_v=2 ./bin/mesos-tests.sh --gtest_filter="Foo.Bar" --verbose`

That will enable all common `VLOG` levels of mesos. Those however usually are not meant for users but for developers. So don't expect their output to be too user friendly.

Comment: Use ./bin/mesos-tests.sh --gtest_list_tests could list all unit tests

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that http_proxy & https_proxy is set to some proxy and some Mesos tests need to visit local Mesos via 127.0.0.1.